# Rails RJS AJAX Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs

Rails - 3.0 - Trying to make an ajax call but I run into an error.

Controller - Home

```
def test
end
```

View - home#index

```
<div class="test">
Testing here
</div><%= link_to 'Test', test_path, :remote=>true %>
```

View - test.rjs

```
page[:test].replace_html :partial => "home/blah"
```

When I click on the link I get this -

```
 try {
    $("test").update("blah blah blah blah");
    } catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('$(\"test\").update(\"blah blah blah blah\");'); throw e }
```

Any help or advice greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great Post on an example of using Rails3 + CRUD + UJS.

http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7